# Client denied by server configuration /app/etc/config.php

Tags: magento2

I just installed Magento 2 in XAMPP server.Now when i open my admin pannel 
it keeps loading and loading and never stops.

I checked the server logs and it shows:

client denied by server configuration: C:/xampp/htdocs/mymagento2/app/etc/config.php

Answer (score 0):

It means the access to that particular directory is denied by apache.

In Apache 2.2, in the config file (or in your virtualhost, add the following rule.)

```
<Directory C:/xampp/htdocs/mymagento2/app/>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Apache 2.4

```
<Directory C:/xampp/htdocs/mymagento2/app/>
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Edit: If it doesn't work, please try the following. I just had a look at the Magento github repo and noticed that it has an .htaccess file inside the app/ folder with the following content. (that is C:/xampp/htdocs/mymagento2/app/.htaccess)

Change the content of that to following:

```
#Order deny,allow
#Deny from all
```

But remember this is basically you are allowing anyone to access some sensitive areas of your application. If it fixes your issue,  then you had a problem with file permissions. So you need to change the permissions.

Comment: i have to add this rule in Apache(httpd.conf) file,is'nt it?

Comment: Yes, in that file.

Comment: var/www/project directory is this for linux os??,am using windows,my project directory is C:\xampp\htdocs\mymagento2

Comment: it is'nt working ,admin pannel is again keeps loading and loading.And the error log shows the same error

Comment: What version of Apache you are using ?

Comment: Also, see if you have an .htaccess file inside C:/xampp/htdocs/mymagento2/app/ folder. Can you paste the content in it here?

Comment: Apache 2.4.25 and XAMPP 3.2.2.i have changed the content in .htacess file,but no use

Comment: Sir,still no change